# Numpy: finding nonzero values along arbitrary dimension

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, iteration, array-broadcasting

It seems I just cannot solve this in Numpy: I have a matrix, with an arbitrary number of dimensions, ordered in an arbitrary way. Inside this matrix, there is always one dimension I am interested in (as I said, the position of this dimension is not always the same). Now, I want to find the first nonzero value along this dimension. In fact, I need the index of that value to perform some operations on the value itself.
An example: if my matrix `a` is `n x m x p` and the dimension I am interested in is number 1, I would do something like:

```
for ii in xrange(a.shape[0]):
   for kk in xrange(a.shape[2]):
      myview = np.squeeze(a[ii, :, kk])
      firsti = np.nonzero(myview)[0][0]
      myview[firsti] = dostuff
```

Apart from performance considerations, I really do not know how to do this having different number of dimensions, and having the dimension I am interested in an arbitrary position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abuse [`np.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) for your purpose. Here, you can specify the `axis` which you are interested in, where `0` is along columns, `1` is along rows, and so on. You just need an array which contains the same value for all elements that are not zero. You can achieve that by doing `a != 0`, as this will contain `False` (meaning `0`) for all zero-elements and `True` (meaning `1`) for all non-zero-elements. Now `np.argmax(a != 0, axis=1)` would give you the first non-zero element along the `1` axis.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 4],[1, 0, 2],[0, 0, 1]])
# a = [[0, 1, 4],
#      [1, 0, 2],
#      [0, 0, 1]]

print(np.argmax(a!=0, axis=0))
# >>> array([1, 0, 0]) -> along columns

print(np.argmax(a!=0, axis=1))
# >>> array([1, 0, 2]) -> along rows
```

This will also work for higher dimension, but the output is less instructive, as it is hard to imagine.